# How to run the same machine on both VMware and Virtualbox?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware, kali-linux, vmware-workstation

I am learning linux and pentesting using Kali on Vmware Workstation Pro. I downloaded some vulnerable machines from Vulnhub for practicing. Apparently, some machines do not work on VMware, and I need Virtualbox for them. I am aware that both the programs can coexist, but cannot be run together (unstable). Hence, I was wondering if I could use my Kali machine on either of the programs, without modifying, or changing any settings. If that is possible, then do I just import the machine in Virtualbox and start running it? Or do I need to do anything else?

Comment: VMWare doesn’t support the virtual HDD format that VirtualBox uses without running the file through a conversion process but that process creates a new file.

Comment: so you mean the only solution is to export as OVF/OVA?

Comment: I know nothing about the VMs your trying to run.  You can [edit] your question and I can submit a detailed answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VirtualBox has full support for the disk formats of VDI, VHD and even VMware's
VMDK format.

You can share the disk, but not the virtual machine itself.
You will need to create two virtual machines, one for each virtualization product,
but you may share the disk in VMDK format.